# Matlab: cumsum or cumtrapz which is appropriate for time integral?

Tags: matlab, integral, cumsum

I have a time varying signal (i.e. a pulse) which I need to calculate the time integral (integrated over the whole of the pulse) for and then evaluate the max./final integral value.

To investigate the appropriate function I have defined a square wave in MATLAB:

```
t=0:0.1:10;
x=square(t);
```

with amplitude varying between -1 and +1 (length of x is 101).

If I plot `a = cumsum(x)` and `b = cumtrapz(t,x)` I find similar shaped (saw-tooth) plots but

> max(a) = 33

and

> max(b) = 3.2

I'm not sure which is the appropriate integral final value (maximum) to use?

Comment: the short answer is `trapz` or `cumsum(x) / samplerate (0.1 in your case)` since all cumsum is doing is add each sample (at 0.1 t), so in t= 1, 10 samples are added, in your case, 10 or -10 which is wrong because the sample rate is 0.1 not 1.

Comment: ah yes! thanks. cumsum(x)/ (1/ts) where ts=0.1 gives max(a) = 3.3

Comment: yes, but note it is the sample rate not just 1/t, it is the number in between t = 0:0.1:10

Comment: *i meant cumtrapz not trapz

Comment: yes I knew what you meant

Comment: It should probably be noted that the method using cumtrapz integrates using the trapezoidal method and the methods using cumsum/samplerate corresponds to the Euler method (Riemann sum). Whereas the trapezoidal is more accurate.